# How can you override the FirstWindow shutdown mode in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've read up on how WPF handles the shutdown event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx

However in my project I haven't specified the StartupURI in the application xaml. However when the first window of my application closes, the entire application closes.

One way I have handled this so far is to create an empty window, and choose to not show it. This way I can go on to close/open windows without WPF calling shutdown when the user chooses to close the first window.

However my solution doesn't feel elegant, is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `OnExplicitShutdown` if you don't want it to close when the last window is gone?

Comment: Ah, of course. I took the article to suggest that it wasn't possible to use OnExplicityShutdown in WPF. My mistake.